# Postgres: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to import a csv file into postgres table.
However getting this error:

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb4
```

Command i am using is:

```
\copy classified_advertisement from '/tmp/jangoads.csv' using delimiters ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not in UTF-8. Find out its actual encoding and specify that.